# Argument passed to JS method inefficent

Tags: javascript

Will anyone please tell me what is wrong with this snippet?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function anotherWindow(msg, myWidth, myHeight)
{
 theWindow=window.open('','','width=myWidth,height=myHeight');
 theWindow.document.write(msg);
 theWindow.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="One more window" onclick="anotherWindow('Here is the  window',200,100)" />

</body>
</html>
```

While the first argument (msg) is successfully passed to method .write, the two arguments related to window size in method .open bring no result —the method sticks to some defaults.

What is wrong with my understanding of variable passing?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments are being passed the right way, but they are not being `used` the right way.

```
theWindow=window.open('','','width=myWidth,height=myHeight');
```

You have `myWidth` and `myHeight` in quotes which will not tell javascript that those are variables. Those two have to be outside quotes.

Like this:

```
theWindow=window.open('','','width='+myWidth+',height='+myHeight);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually substitute in the values of the variables.

```
theWindow=window.open('','','width='+myWidth+',height='+myHeight);
```